# Pspice: parametric gain of dependant source

Tags: simulation, spice, pspice

I am trying to create my first circuits in Pspice and I want to implement this command:

E1 node1 node2 VALUE={I(E1)*V(2,0)}

From my understanding, it represents a voltage-dependant voltage source which multiplies the voltage V(2,0) with the current flowing through the E source itself.

However, I can't find a way to achieve this functionality in Pspice using the Property Editor and when I use {I(E1)} as the gain of the E source I get an error. What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not a PSpice expert, but try putting a 0-ohm resistor or 0-V voltage source in series with the VCVS, and use the current through that instead of the current through the VCVS itself.

Comment: If that doesn't work (I don't see any examples that use a current in the expression in the PSpice manual I found online), put a CCVS with its control branch in series with your VCVS, and use its output as the controlling voltage for your VCVS.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the suggestion. I am not sure about something. The VCVS is supposed to be controlled by V(2,0). How is it possible that I could control it from the CCVS too?

Answer (score 1):

PSpice's syntax for in-line equations is the following if you want to multiply a voltage by a coefficient:

E1 1 0 Value = { V(2,3)*4 } ; the voltage source delivers V(2,3) multiplied by 4

G1 2 0 Value = { I(V1)*5 } ; the devices sources the current flowing in V1 times 5

If you want to manipulate the current flowing through the source, you will have to add in series with it a dummy 0-V source and use it to measure the current and multiply (for instance) by a coefficient:

E1 node1 node2 Value = { I(V1)*V(2,0) }

Keep in mind that the current in the measurement source (or in any component) is positive when leaving the device by its negative pin.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! Sorry if my next question is becoming too specific on the software but I can't find any other example online. Using Capture, how do I set the gain of the E source as I(V1)? I mean if I just type I(V1) in the gain field it results in an error.